# How can I handle an array string through Iteration in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript, loops

I am having this array of string:

```
color = ['red','blue','purple'];
```

I want to print a message that says:

> color in ('red','blue','purple')

If I write this:

```
color.forEach((c) => {
      console.log(`color in ('${c}')`);
    });
```

I am getting this message:

> color in ('red') color in ('blue') color in ('purple')

How can I get the first message?

Comment: don't use `forEach` simply use `console.log(\`color in ('${color}')`)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each color to add quotes to it, then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them together:

```js
const colors = ['red','blue','purple'];
console.log(`color in (${ colors.map(c => `'${c}'`).join(',') })`);
```

Though I'm not sure why you'd do it specifically that way. For debugging purposes, just `console.log('color in', colors)` would do just fine. For user-visible messages, you'd probably just use `colors.join(', ')`, and/or more elaborate formatting using `..., ... and ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```js
color = ['red','blue','purple'];

console.log(`color in (${color.map(item => "'" + item + "'").toString()})`); // color in ('red','blue','purple')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the forEach loop in this way

```js
var color = ['red','blue','purple'];
var str='color in (';
color.forEach(e=>str+="'"+e+"',")
str=str.substring(0,str.length-1)+')';
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be the function `Array.from`.

You can call the function `Array.prototype.join` without param and the comma will be used as a separator.

> [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
>
> Param `separator` **Optional**
>
> Specifies a string to separate each pair of adjacent elements of the array. The separator is converted to a string if necessary. If omitted, the array elements are separated with a comma (","). If `separator` is an empty string, all elements are joined without any characters in between them.

```js
const colors = ['red','blue','purple'];
console.log(`color in (${ Array.from(colors, c => `'${c}'`).join() })`);
```